# How can a debugger break on dynamic loaded libraries?

Tags: c++, memory, winapi, virtual-memory

I think I have a massive understanding problem with the following issue:

Usually the loader will fix the Import Table for the modules that have been loaded, right, so if I set a breakpoint on CreateFileW the debugger can just follow the Import Table address and do so.

However, I've been watching some tutorials lately and often they set breakpoints on e.g. CreateFileW for modules that have been loaded dynamically e.g. LoadLibaryA (while themself are at the entry point of the program).

I'm unable to understand how the debugger can set a breakpoint for a module that yet has not been loaded into the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugging API provides a notification for newly loaded libraries so the debugger can inspect their export table and set breakpoints on matching symbols.